# how to save value from POST method into parameter of Java class?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, post, spring-security

I'm new in Java, and currently try to create my own project, but have a problem with displaying information about user in his main page. Now I need to save a value from my JSP page (/login) which use method POST into parameter of my Java class("Controller").

login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Log in with your account</title>

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/login" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-heading">Log in</h2>

        <div class="form-group ${error != null ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <span>${message}</span>
            <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
                   autofocus="true"/>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
            <span>${error}</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="${contextPath}/registration">Create an account</a></h4>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and UserController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getEmail(), userForm.getConfirmPassword());

        return "redirect:/fillingform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String getEmail(@RequestParam("email") String email) {

        return email;
    }
```

appconfig-security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

        <http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

            <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                        username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password"/>

            <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
        </http>

        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
                <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

        <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
                    class="com.gmail.*">
</beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="encoder"
                    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
            <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:beans>
```

UserDetailsServImpl

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findByEmail(email);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

Read a lot of information, if for real about it,heard recommendation about doPost() method, request.getParameter() and so on, but nothing help ( 
Please help, what logic code I need to put in method "public String getEmail" for getting user Emailfrom POST form.

Thank's.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the `userDetailsServiceImpl`? does it gets the `email` parameter value?

Comment: just tried,returns 'null' (

Comment: So, the parameter `email` to `loadUserByUsername(String email)` is NULL? If yes, first this needs to be fixed. Second, make sure you are returning the `User` object correctly with correct `grantedAuthority`. Lastly, you shouldn't be accessing the email parameter when the user is trying to log-in. Instead, you have to use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal.getUsername();` to get the email.